# AngularJS: ui-router: Do not output link of current state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible **to check state in the view** and don't output the link for current (active) state?

Currently trying:

```
<a ng-if="!$state.includes('dashboard.common')" ui-sref="dashboard.common" >Dashboard</a>
<span ng-if="$state.includes('dashboard.common')">Dashboard</span>
```

Of course, I could decorate it with [ui-sref-active](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active), but I don't want to have link at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with the `ng-if` approach?

Comment: it seems like `$state.includes` doesn't work

Comment: Did you expose `$state` on the scope - i.e. `$scope.$state = $state`?

Comment: good point, thank you

Comment: but still looking for something without `$scope.$state = $state`. Proved example is just to show what I'm going to achieve

Comment: Create a custom directive similar to `ui-sref-active` that applies the equivalent of `ng-if` - ui.router doesn't have such directive built-in

Comment: yes, I'm also thinking about solution of such kind. I wonder why there is no solution from box.

Comment: I can't answer that question authoritatively, but my guess is that `ui-sref-active` covers 80% of use cases, and your use case is fairly easy to create on your own, either with `ng-if` or with a custom directive

Comment: added related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697560/angularjs-correct-way-of-doing-directive-with-dynamic-template-and-replace-opti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31702204/274500)

and my final version is:

```
angular.module('ui')
  .directive('uiLink', function($state) {
    'use strict';

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: [
        '<a ui-sref="{{uiSref}}" ng-if="!isCurrent()" ng-transclude></a>',
        '<span ng-if="isCurrent()" ng-transclude></span>'
      ].join(''),
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.uiSref = attrs.sref;
        scope.isCurrent = function() {
          return $state.includes(attrs.sref);
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

so now you can use this directive like:

```
<ui-link sref="dashboard.common"><span translate="MY_DASHBOARD">Dashboard</span></ui-link>
```