# AngularJS: ui-router: $state.includes does not work for states with default params?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I'm doing

```
$state.includes('courses.all({ clientType: "organizations" })')
```

it returns `undefined`

and it works for

```
$state.includes('courses.all')
```

`clientType` is optional param here (it's 'organizations' by default)

So is it a bug or a feature?

**UPD:**

It does not work just with brackets as well:

```
$state.includes('courses.all()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a featue, $state.includes is checking if the name of state you provided is present in the full state name.

Example: if you have state: `'app.state1.state2.state3'` then state includes will return true for any of those substates.

On the other hand, if you want ot check for state parmas you have to do it in router's `resolve` or in controller directly

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm trying to implement it here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31718716/274500

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
 $state.includes('user.forms.preview', { type: 'patients' })
```

My state looks something like:

```
.state('user.forms.preview', {
  page_title: 'Configuracion datos de Pacientes',
  url: '/preview/:type',
  controller: 'userFormPreviewerCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'whathever.html',
 })
```

well in your case would be:

```
$state.includes('courses.all', { clientType: "organizations" })
```

Comment: it would like to do it not only for 'organizations'